# Ranking effect on changing website topic and language suddenly

Tags: google-ranking

My website language is Bengali and my topic is technology updates, tips and tricks.

I want to change my topic to `Android` and `Web Development`.
The language will be English.

Will it cause problem to the website rank?

Comment: What are you going to do with your old content?   I wouldn't recommend throwing it out, but I also would recommend separating it from the new content.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller my other content will stay as before. I won't delete them. The has there own category like `seo` and I'll use `Android Development/RelatedCat` for new contents.

Comment: Will your content use separate sections of your site with different menus and templates that are language appropriate?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I was asking if google think the topic has changed and decrease it's rank!!

Comment: @StephenOstermiller No what it was before. Previous theme as I'm using `WordPress`

Comment: I'm asking for details because I think they are going to matter.  If you do it right you could be OK, but there are a lot of ways to mess it up.